Is an object returned by a call to an async (external) process fundamentally different from an object that is returned from a 'normal' function?
I am quite new to Javascript, with my main programming experience in assembly language programming of micro-controllers. It has taken quite some time to adjust to it having so many 'system calls', (to do essentially all of the heavy lifting in the language) which to me are often described as being "Javascript functions".
I noticed that methods of the returned object in such cases are reported as containing "native code". I assume then that such code is not written in Javascript.
If it is the case, then those methods on the object returned are not methods in the sense that I understand (that is, Javascript functions) but instead yet other 'system calls'. Perhaps the in-built Object methods in Javascript are also native code. But here there could be a difference; the latter being part of the Javascript engine, the former being part of the browser etc. implementation.
I would like to know if there are any important distinctions between methods of an object returned from such 'system calls' compared to methods of normal Javascript objects".
To me the term 'system call' or 'browser call' then rather than 'Javascript function' would make the distinction clear. For example, the phrase "asynchronous Javascript function" is a misnomer.
Thanks for reading.

there's no difference for your javascript code, it consumes objects in the same format

To understand the distinction that you see, it would help if you provide a link to where they >>are reported as containing "native code"<<, and examples.
